# Peridot-php Fatal Error in console while working fine on browser

Tags: php, fatal-error, psr-4

I was reading and working on the Case study from the book The Clean Architecture, here is the link for [current code](https://github.com/ravikumar8/cleanphp) if you guys want to see  tried every possible way but not able to solve the issue.

Here is the issue

Getting fatal error
Fatal error: Class 'Webloper\CleanPhp\Invoicer\Domain\Entity\Order' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\cleanphp\specs\domain\service\invoice-factory.spec.php on line 8

so added public folder and index.php file to check its working on browser also added vendors autoload.php and its working fine.

so again added vendors autoload to invoice-factory.spec.php file but its give another error can't find stream.

Comment: If you move your mouse over the down vote button a small tool tip should show you the most common down vote reason.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Epodax modified question not sure what else to write here. btw thanks

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue do the following:

make sure your psr-4 is added to your composer.json

```
 "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "CleanPhp\\Invoicer\\": ["src/"]
    }
},
```

next make sure you have the following packages are added to your composer.json file

```
 "require-dev": {
    "peridot-php/peridot": "~1.8",
    "peridot-php/leo": "~1.2"
}
```

then run

`composer update`

then run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and that should fix the issue.